# Standard Time Measurement Unit

Tags: jprofiler

in JProfiler, is there a way to force the UI to always shows time measurement in one unit, ie. milliseconds? The current behaviour is it will auto adjust the number to a higher or lower unit, i.e. seconds or nanoseconds, which is a bit annoying to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the "View settings" of each view that shows times or memory sizes, you can switch the time scale from "Automatic" to a fixed unit.

[image]